# Why does 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... converge to -1 in the 2-adic number system?

Tags: sequences-and-series, p-adic-number-theory, divergent-series

From this page, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNumber.html, the norm of $x = \frac{p^a r}{s}$ for r, s relatively prime to p, and a maximized, over the p-adic numbers, is $p^{-a}$. If we take the norms of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n$ over the 2-adic number system, they are always positive. So how does this lead to the conclusion that the final sum is -1?

Comment: Because $(1-2)\sum_{n=0}^N 2^n = 1-2^{N+1}$ which converges to $1$ as $N\to \infty$ (the $2$-adic integers are the completion of the integers adding the limits of sequences that converge for the absolute value $|2^a (2b+1)|_2=2^{-a}$)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The difference between $1+2+4+8+\cdots+2^N$ and $-1$ is $2^{N+1}$, which goes to $0$ ($2$-adically) as $N\to\infty$

Comment: The familiar order on the real line has nothing whatever to do with the $p$-adic metric, no matter which $p$ you’re considering. You can easily find a pair $a,b$ of rational numbers, one positive and the other negative, both large in the ordinary sense, that yet are very close $2$-adically. The moral is that there are no “negative $p$-adic numbers”; a consequence is that in any of the standard ways of writing a $p$-adic number, a minus sign does not occur.

Comment: This is also related to geometric series formula $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$. You can use it "$p$-adically" even for outside the "convergence interval", i.e. $x=2$ gives $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n = \frac{1}{1-2} = -1$ in $p$-adic sense.

Answer (score 3):

The $p$-adic world is totally different from real world. For example a disk (a circle and its inside) has no fixed center. Every point of the disk is a center! Also a circle in $p$-adic world contains balls of same radius in its circumference!! Any triangle is isosceles and is you have a square in $p$-adic world, then the diameter of square is less than its side, and ...

Specially there is no concept of positive or negative $p$-adic number. So it can make sense that a sum of powers of $2$ converges to $-1$.

You  also may note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nn!=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(n+1)!-n!\\
=-1+\lim_{n\to\infty} (n+1)!=-1+0=-1$$

$p$-adic objects realm on strange tides.

Comment: I would add one more:  in 2-adics every integer is a triangular number and a pentagonal number.

Comment: @OscarLanzi You are a $p$-adic world's fan. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "a circle in [the] $p$-adic world contains its interior"? And what by that statement about squares and diameters?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I rephrased about circle and its interior. Also since any triangle is isosceles with equal sides longer than the other, then diameter happens to be smaller than sides (In fact existence of square needs to be discussed because the geometry of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ seems to be elliptic.

Comment: Thanks for the correction of the first. I think the square thing should just be taken out, I have never encountered that, one would first have to define what a "square" and its diagonal is even supposed to mean in a general metric space etc. It has little to do with the OP's specific question anyway.